# AWS DYNAMO DB query with multiple condition

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to fetch details from dynamo db using the bellow query in this DOMAIN and SERVICE are just key(non primary key)

```
let params = {
    TableName: asset_table,
    ConsistentRead: true,
    ProjectionExpression: 'ID,SERVICE',
    KeyConditionExpression: "DOMAIN = :service_name AND SERVICE EQ :service_domain",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
         ":service_name": {"S":service },
         ":service_domain": {"S":domain}
    }
};
docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        onComplete(err);
    } else {
        console.log(data);
        onComplete(null, {
            data
        });
    }
});
```

this give error as given bellow

```
{
"message": "ExpressionAttributeValues can only be specified when using expressions: FilterExpression is null",
"code": "ValidationException",
"time": "2019-01-09T09:47:09.180Z",
"requestId": "0G3C02E6251S2H1IQ2LQUTN04JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
"statusCode": 400,
"retryable": false,
"retryDelay": 8.070453867451622
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scan` method does not accept a `KeyConditionExpression`, in `params`. Instead you must use the `FilterExpression` param.

The error is telling you this as it can see your `ExpressionAttributeValues` but no `FilterExpression` to use them.

According to AWS Docs - [Working With Scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression):

> The syntax for a filter expression is identical to that of a condition
>   expression. Filter expressions can use the same comparators,
>   functions, and logical operators as a condition expression. For more
>   information, [Condition Expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html).

Checkout DDB Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property) for full details on how to use the `scan` method.

Comment: is it possible to do FilterExpression with AND condition

Comment: I have not personally used a `FilterExpression` in this way but yes according to the documentation it should. I've updated my answer above with the details.

Comment: is it possible to delete using multiple condition

Comment: I have just tested, it definitely is possible to use `AND` operator in `FilterExpression`.

Comment: I need to delete the find result is it possible using single query if so plz give the redirect me that also

Comment: According to the docs the `delete` method does accept `ConditionExpression` so I expect it is possible. If not you should be able to collect ids with `scan` then use that data with either `delete` or `batchWrite` to delete entries.

Comment: You can't delete multiple items with a single query. You would need to use batchWrite to combine the individual deletes

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
const paramsVehicles = {
    TableName: "vehicles",
    FilterExpression: "#manufacturer = :manufacturer and #modelName = :modelName",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#manufacturer": "manufacturer",
        "#modelName": "modelName",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":manufacturer": "SEAT",
        ":modelName": "Ateca",
    }
};
```

I used a different table and model but the approach is generic and can be used in the asked example.